# Can't install lme4 package in R 3.6.3. on macOS Catalina

Tags: r, macos, lme4, install.packages

I can't get lme4 to install (it was working fine, then I stepped away for a while, did an update or two in the interim, now the same code has stopped working).

The code I'm using is:

```
install.packages("lme4",  dependencies = TRUE)
library(lme4)
```

The error I get is:

```
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary  source needs_compilation
Rcpp  1.0.4 1.0.4.6              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)
```

First question - does this suggest that the problem is with the Rcpp package which lme4 is dependent on?

I type:

```
y
```

Second question - is this the right thing to do?

I get the following message back:

```
The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/fr/x0qmcc0d3s1grpw1dc946sch0000gn/T//RtmpCLLS34/downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘Rcpp’

trying URL 'https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/src/contrib/Rcpp_1.0.4.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2751467 bytes (2.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.6 MB
* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/fr/x0qmcc0d3s1grpw1dc946sch0000gn/T/RtmpCLLS34/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("lme4", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
```

Third question - what does the above message mean and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Personally I would select No, install the pre compiled version.  It is unlikely the incremental update is critical, if possible read the release notes at the developer's page.

Comment: Saying No appears to have fixed the problem! Thank you!